# Matching a value with more than one column

Tags: r

For a data frame like this:

| c | d |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | NA |
| 2 | NA |
| 1 | NA |
| 3 | NA |
| 2 | NA |

I would like to find the maximum "ID" where the value of "c" corresponds to either the value of "a" or the value of "b". For this "ID", I want to return "value" and store it in "d".

| ID | a | b | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 10 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 6 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 7 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 | 12 |

Hence, the required output is:

| c | d |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 12 |

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g., With subsetting by matching:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# First pivot longer and get the highest ID per your matching value
mydat_long <- mydat %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "key", values_to = "keyvalue", cols = c(a,b)) %>%
  group_by(keyvalue) %>% 
  slice(which.max(ID))

# use this to match to your lookup "c" (avoid such names, very dangerous to use "c" as a name for objects or variables in R
lu$d <- mydat_long$value[match(lu$c, mydat_long$keyvalue)]

lu
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       c     d
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3     2
#> 2     2    12
#> 3     1    12
#> 4     3     2
#> 5     2    12
```

Data

```
# devtools::install_github("alistaire47/read.so")
lu <- read.so::read_md("| c | d     |
|---|-------|
| 3 | NA    |
| 2 | NA    |
| 1 | NA    |
| 3 | NA    |
| 2 | NA    |")
mydat <- read.so::read_md("| ID | a | b | value |
|----|---|---|-------|
| 1  | 1 | 3 | 7     |
| 2  | 2 | 1 | 10    |
| 3  | 3 | 2 | 4     |
| 4  | 2 | 1 | 6     |
| 5  | 1 | 2 | 3     |
| 6  | 3 | 1 | 4     |
| 7  | 1 | 3 | 2     |
| 8  | 1 | 2 | 12    |")
```

Comment: as pointed out as comment in the code, but here for better visibility - it's a VERY bad idea to name your column "c"

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much! Regarding the comment about naming a column "c", you are right of course. I accidently named it like this for the purpose of the question, my actual column names have different names.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm referring to your original dataframe as `df` and the dataframe with 4 columns as `other_df`.

```
f <- function(c_val, other_df){
  sub <- other_df[(other_df$a == c_val | other_df$b == c_val),]
  d_val <- sub[sub$id == max(sub$id), "value"]
  return(d_val)
}

df$d <- sapply(df$c, f, other_df = other_df)
```

The function will return the correct value for a particular value of `c`, then you use `sapply` to apply the function to every value in `c`.

Answer (score 1):

@Tor97, this should work.

```
# Load Libraries
library('tidyverse')

# Read in tables
table <- read_csv('table.csv')
table    

results <- read_csv('results.csv')
results$d <- as.numeric(results$d)
results

# Finds the max ID and return Value
for (i in 1:nrow(results)){
  results[i,2] <- table[table$ID == max(table[table$a == results$c[i],1], table[table$b == results$c[i],1]),4]
}
```

Here are the results:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      c     d
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     2
2     2    12
3     1    12
4     3     2
5     2    12
```